# Django search field in the database

Tags: python, html, django

is it possible to change my display employe to a search block because when I select the numbers it displays a list which is not practical when I have a lot of numbers in my database.

[add info to an existing employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS2UP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `__str__()` [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#str) for your `Employee` model, it result would be seen in admin dropdown

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```